# GoogleShopping Magento Error:

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I have installed and configured the Mage_GoogleShopping module on a Magento 1.7.0.2 Shop. When trying to add products to Google Shopping, /var/log/system.log displays the following errors:

```
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePrice.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePrice.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePrice.php' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/local:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/community:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/core:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib:.:')  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateFrom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateFrom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateFrom.php' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/local:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/community:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/core:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib:.:')  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateTo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateTo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateTo.php' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/local:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/community:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/core:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib:.:')  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/Name.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/Name.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/Name.php' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/local:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/community:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/core:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib:.:')  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/Description.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/Description.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-09-12T12:31:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attribute/Description.php' for inclusion (include_path='/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/local:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/community:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/app/code/core:/path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib:.:')  in /path/to/shop/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

The problem has been reported several times in the Magento forums, however I have not found a solution for this.

It is definitely no problem with permissions. The files do not exist.

Comment: @Guus: I can't see how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400150/magento-1-7-getmodel-in-script-outside-web-application-fails is similar to this one??

Comment: You're right. I can't remember, I will delete it. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The GoogleShopping-Module tries to load an Attribute-Model for all needed attributes "on-the-fly". If this model doesn't exist in Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Attributes/... an error occurs...

To override the method '_createAttribute' in this class 'Mage_GoogleShopping_Model_Type' fix it for me:

```
 /**
 * Create attribute instance using attribute's name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Mage_GoogleShopping_Model_Attribute
 */
protected function _createAttribute($name)
{
    $modelName = 'googleshopping/attribute_' . $this->_prepareModelName($name);
    $useDefault = false;

    $className = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getModelClassName($modelName);

    if (class_exists($className)) {
        $attributeModel = Mage::getModel($modelName);
        $useDefault = !$attributeModel;
    } else {
        $useDefault = true;
    }
    if ($useDefault) {
        $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('googleshopping/attribute_default');
    }
    $attributeModel->setName($name);

    return $attributeModel;
}
```