# Magento 1.7 - getModel in script outside web application fails

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

```
<global>
    <models>
        <starmall_shipment>
            <class>Starmall_Shipment_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>starmall_shipment_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </starmall_shipment>

        <starmall_shipment_mysql4>
            <class>Starmall_Shipment_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <shipment>
                    <table>starmall_shipment</table>
                </shipment>             
            </entities>
        </starmall_shipment_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
```

My custom grid in the backend is working and I see the grid with data in it.
As a debug test I have in my Grid.php in `_prepareCollection`:

```
    $x = Mage::getModel('starmall_shipment/shipment');
    $x->load(3);

    var_dump($x);  // WORKS and I get information
```

When I run this in a standalone script:

```
<?php
    define("MAGE_BASE_DIR", "/home/users/xxx/xxx");
    require_once MAGE_BASE_DIR . '/app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $x = Mage::getModel('starmall_shipment/shipment');
        $x->load(3);

    var_dump($x);   
?>
```

I see this error:

```
No such file or directory  in /home/users/xxx/xxx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
Failed opening 'Mage/Starmall/Shipment/Model/Shipment.php'
```

Why does it prepend `Mage` in front of the model?
What can be wrong in my config?

---

**ADDED INFORMATION:**

/app/etc/Starmall_Shipment.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Starmall_Shipment>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Starmall_Shipment>
</modules>
```

---

**THE REAL PROBLEM (POSSIBLY)**

My Magento hosting provider puts this tag default int `/app/etc/local.xml` when installing Magento.

```
<cache>
  <backend>memcached</backend>
  <memcached>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <host>unix:///path/to/memcached.sock</host>
        <persistent>0</persistent>
        <port>0</port>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </memcached>
</cache>
```

If I comment this tag out then I don't need to use `loadModules()` in my script.
I wonder if I need to turn this back on when going into production mode?

Comment: Have you tested using Magento outside its directory with stock components (not your own module)? That'd be the first thing to test, to ensure you are doing that correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have tested with Magento core models which work correctly. Also I have other custom modules/tables with same configuration which work also properly. Except this model gives this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look how Magento cron works - it works as standalone script also (cron.php) and copy-paste code to your custom module.
Main things:

```
 require 'app/Mage.php';
 ...
 Mage::getConfig()->init()
```

Also it seems like modules not loaded
Try to add after init config:

```
Mage::getConfig()->loadModules();
```

Comment: Thanks! `loadModules()` solves it! But I am still curious WHY only this module is not loaded? I have other modules with models declared in the same way, but those work in a script without having to do `loadModules()`

Comment: loadModules() is always executed if you call Mage::app() the first time. So in your case the module is not loaded until the second call of loadModules(). This is indeed strange. Do you have some module related configuration in `app/etc/local.xml` by chance?

Comment: @fab I checked my `/app/etc/local.xml` and I think there is indeed something which causes this weird problem. I have added info to the question at the bottom. If I comment out the `cache` tag my original script works fine. Thanks for the suggestion! This is the probably the real problem, but already awarded the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it prepend Mage in front of the model? What can be wrong in my config?

To see, where this is happening, look at `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()`:

```
    if (empty($className)) {
        if (!empty($config)) {
            $className = $config->getClassName();
        }
        if (empty($className)) {
            $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
        }
        if (!empty($class)) {
            $className .= '_'.$class;
        }
        $className = uc_words($className);
    }
```

This can mean one of two things:

1. The `$config` node was not found (`global/models/starmall_shipment`)
2. The node has no `class` or `model` child or it is empty

In your case it looks like (1), so the question remains, why is your config not loaded. You assured that the config itself is correct, so the problem must be that the module is not loaded.

Can you post your module declaration file from `app/etc/modules`?

Comment: I added my `/app/etc/modules/Starmall_Shipment.xml` and show that my model is in the `global` section. I have more custom modules with models and only this one seems to be not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It is prepending Mage because it is one of the core directories.. In my server, I see /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/ as a navigable path.

Put your standalone scripts in your mage base dir, and use the following code at the "beginning"

```
<?php
   require_once 'app/Mage.php';
   Mage::app('admin');
```

Hopefully this will be enough to get your magento up and running, then you can figure out why the paths aren't working the way you expect.

Comment: Tried it but same results. Weird is that I have other custom tables that are working correctly in my test scripts. This is the only one I have this problem with. Compared config.xml files but cannot find any difference than in the module naming.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether compilation mode is enabled in your store(System->Tools->Compilation).If yes then re-run compilation process

Comment: I have compile mode disabled. To be sure enabled and recompiled and disabled again. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your model under `<global>` tag in `config.xml` like

```
<global>    
    <models>
        <starmall_shipment>
            <class>Starmall_Shipment_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>starmall_shipment_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </starmall_shipment>

        <starmall_shipment_mysql4>
            <class>Starmall_Shipment_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <shipment>
                    <table>starmall_shipment</table>
                </shipment>             
            </entities>
        </starmall_shipment_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
```

because you are accessing if from outside the module.

Comment: I checked this and it is defined in the `global` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in `app/etc/local.xml`, but it shouldn't be solved by calling `Mage::app()->loadModules()`.

The real issue is that someone (most likely for debugging purposes) disabled local modules.

Just change

```
<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
```

to

```
<disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
```

in `app/etc/local.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

CarComp is write, after adding 
  Mage::app('admin');
the 
  Mage::getConfig()->init() working like a charm.