# Magento Mage class causes server error 500 in own php script

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I got a few problems with the Mage Class, when we try to call any static method, e. g. in my case:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

It always causes an error 500. It´s been used in an own php design file.

Also, this post didn´t resolve the problem: [Magento 1.7 - getModel in script outside web application fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400150/magento-1-7-getmodel-in-script-outside-web-application-fails)

I searched a lot in the internet and found out, that

```
Mage::getModel();
```

is a factory method, so I actually don´t need to call

```
Mage::getConfig()->init();
Mage::getConfig()->loadModules();
```

Help me, please!

Edit: I solved the error with this code:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $prodCollection->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_name');
```

The main problem was, that this line was missing:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be caused by this:

```
Mage::getModel()->('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

This is wrong. First of all `getModel` expects at least a parameter. Second, there is no method name here `->('catalog/product')`. Your code should be:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Also make sure that `Mage.php` is included in your script otherwise the class is not found.